# How to change stroke color of SVG on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have a web page with svg logo with drawing animation .

I want to change color of stroke from green to white on hover any way to achieve that ?

My logo is "V" shaped SVG

I want to change that stroke dash color from green to white on hovering mouse using CSS

I tried adding div element and adding hover to it but it' didn't worked at all any help would be great.

> P.S It would be better if you view in full screen

```js
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;


for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }

  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML ='';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    var char = content.charAt(i);
    if(char === " ")
        letter = document.createElement('br');
    else
        letter.innerHTML = char;
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }

  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 4000);

var i = 0;
var txt = 'Hi , ';
var speed = 100;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter()

var j = 0;
var txt1 = 'I\'m Vivank a ,';
var speed = 100;

function typeWriter1() {
  if (j < txt1.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += txt1.charAt(j);
    j++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter1, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter1()
```

```css
:root {
  --mainColor: #fff;
}

body{
  background-color: #252627;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bglogo{
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  right: 15vh;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 65vh;
  z-index: 0;
}


.home-page{
  width: 100%;
  will-change: contents;
  height: 90%;
  min-height: 566px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
path {
  fill: #252627;
  stroke: #00ffdc;
  animation: my_animation 2s linear forwards, filling .2s linear 2s forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 400; /* need to ... */
  stroke-dashoffset: 400; /* ... match */
}

@keyframes my_animation {
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}

@keyframes filling {
  to {fill: #ff0046}
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 40%;
  max-height: 90%;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 64px;
}


.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #003366;
}


p {
  color: var(--mainColor);
  text-decoration: none;
}

p:hover {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--mainColor);
}

@supports not(-webkit-text-stroke: 2px red) {
  p:hover {
    text-shadow:
      3px 3px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor);
  }

}
.top-tags{
  bottom: auto;
  top: 0px;
}

.tags{
      color: #515152;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 80px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
    }

.home-page #demo::before{
  content: '<h1>';
  font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
  color: #515152;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -35px;
}

.home-page .word::after{
  content: '</h1>';
  font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
  color: #515152;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  -webkit-animation: myanim2 1s 1.7s backwards;
  animation: myanim2 1s 1.7s backwards;
}
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
      -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
       -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
         -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
          -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
              user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                    supported by Chrome and Opera */
  }

  @keyframes myanim2 {
    0%   { opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}

}
@-webkit-keyframes myanim2 {
    0%   { opacity: 0;  }
    100% {opacity: 1;}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vivank Sharma</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master_responsive.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=La+Belle+Aurore" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="noselect">


    <div class="page">
      <div class="bglogo">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 89.999 89.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 89.999 89.999;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
          <path d="M89.551,24.201c-5.029,28.863-33.127,53.301-41.577,58.883c-8.454,5.582-16.163-2.236-18.96-8.148   c-3.201-6.738-12.793-43.285-15.307-46.311C11.195,25.596,3.656,31.65,3.656,31.65L0,26.768c0,0,15.307-18.623,26.957-20.951   c12.35-2.469,12.332,19.318,15.301,31.416c2.873,11.701,4.807,18.398,7.312,18.398c2.514,0,7.311-6.525,12.562-16.531   c5.264-10.016-0.225-18.857-10.505-12.568C55.738,1.395,94.578-4.65,89.551,24.201z" fill="#ff0043"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>


    <div class="home-page" style="opacity=1;">

      <span class="tags top-tags"> &lt;html&gt;<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt; </span>
    <div class="text">

      <p id="demo"></p><br>
      <p id="demo1"></p>
      <br>
      <p>
        <span class="word wisteria">wonderful developer</span>
        <span class="word belize">geek developer</span>
        <span class="word pomegranate">web developer</span>
        <span class="word green">android developer</span>
        <span class="word midnight">ML-AI developer</span>
      </p>



    </div>

    <span class="tags bottom-tags"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/body&gt;<br> &lt;/html&gt; </span>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/typewriter.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add This CSS

```
.bglogo path:hover{
  stroke: #00f;
}
.bglogo{
z-index: 99;
}
```

```js
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;


for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }

  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML ='';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    var char = content.charAt(i);
    if(char === " ")
        letter = document.createElement('br');
    else
        letter.innerHTML = char;
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }

  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 4000);

var i = 0;
var txt = 'Hi , ';
var speed = 100;

function typeWriter() {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter()

var j = 0;
var txt1 = 'I\'m Vivank a ,';
var speed = 100;

function typeWriter1() {
  if (j < txt1.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML += txt1.charAt(j);
    j++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter1, speed);
  }
}

typeWriter1()
```

```css
:root {
  --mainColor: #fff;
}

body{
  background-color: #252627;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bglogo{
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  right: 15vh;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 65vh;
  z-index: 99;
}


.home-page{
  width: 100%;
  will-change: contents;
  height: 90%;
  min-height: 566px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 5%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
path {
  fill: #252627;
  stroke: #00ffdc;
  animation: my_animation 2s linear forwards, filling .2s linear 2s forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 400; /* need to ... */
  stroke-dashoffset: 400; /* ... match */
}
.bglogo path:hover{
  stroke: #fff;
}

@keyframes my_animation {
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}

@keyframes filling {
  to {fill: #ff0046}
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 40%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 40%;
  max-height: 90%;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 64px;
}


.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #003366;
}


p {
  color: var(--mainColor);
  text-decoration: none;
}

p:hover {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--mainColor);
}

@supports not(-webkit-text-stroke: 2px red) {
  p:hover {
    text-shadow:
      3px 3px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor);
  }

}
.top-tags{
  bottom: auto;
  top: 0px;
}

.tags{
      color: #515152;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 80px;
      font-size: 18px;
      font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
    }

.home-page #demo::before{
  content: '<h1>';
  font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
  color: #515152;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -35px;
}

.home-page .word::after{
  content: '</h1>';
  font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
  color: #515152;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  -webkit-animation: myanim2 1s 1.7s backwards;
  animation: myanim2 1s 1.7s backwards;
}
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
      -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
       -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
         -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
          -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
              user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                    supported by Chrome and Opera */
  }

  @keyframes myanim2 {
    0%   { opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}

}
@-webkit-keyframes myanim2 {
    0%   { opacity: 0;  }
    100% {opacity: 1;}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vivank Sharma</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master_responsive.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=La+Belle+Aurore" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="noselect">


    <div class="page">
      <div class="bglogo">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 89.999 89.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 89.999 89.999;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
          <path d="M89.551,24.201c-5.029,28.863-33.127,53.301-41.577,58.883c-8.454,5.582-16.163-2.236-18.96-8.148   c-3.201-6.738-12.793-43.285-15.307-46.311C11.195,25.596,3.656,31.65,3.656,31.65L0,26.768c0,0,15.307-18.623,26.957-20.951   c12.35-2.469,12.332,19.318,15.301,31.416c2.873,11.701,4.807,18.398,7.312,18.398c2.514,0,7.311-6.525,12.562-16.531   c5.264-10.016-0.225-18.857-10.505-12.568C55.738,1.395,94.578-4.65,89.551,24.201z" fill="#ff0043"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>


    <div class="home-page" style="opacity=1;">

      <span class="tags top-tags"> &lt;html&gt;<br> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;body&gt; </span>
    <div class="text">

      <p id="demo"></p><br>
      <p id="demo1"></p>
      <br>
      <p>
        <span class="word wisteria">wonderful developer</span>
        <span class="word belize">geek developer</span>
        <span class="word pomegranate">web developer</span>
        <span class="word green">android developer</span>
        <span class="word midnight">ML-AI developer</span>
      </p>



    </div>

    <span class="tags bottom-tags"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/body&gt;<br> &lt;/html&gt; </span>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/typewriter.js"></script>
</html>
```